# open excel file on the above folder with watir/Ruby

Tags: ruby

At moment I am open an Excel file like this

```
excel = WIN32OLE::new("excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('T:\\PointOfSale\\Projects\\Automated Testing\\MasterFile.xls')
worksheet = workbook.WorkSheets(1) # Get first workbook
site = worksheet.Range('A2').Value # Get the value at cell in worksheet.
```

and its fine but when i move the scrip to a server i am getting an error message that the Path/file cannot be found. So i decide to user a generic way like when i open a text files

```
excel = WIN32OLE::new("excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('../../../../Automated Testing/MasterFile.xls')
worksheet = workbook.WorkSheets(1) # Get first workbook
site = worksheet.Range('A2').Value # Get the value at cell in worksheet.
```

but i get an error message:

> T:/PointOfSale/Projects/Automated Testing/CSA/Branch_Test/Res Processing/CancelRes/Canc_BE.rb:23:in `method_missing': (in OLE method`Open': ) (WIN32OLERuntimeError)
>       OLE error code:800A03EC in Microsoft Excel
>         '../../../../Automated Testing/MasterFile.xls' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.
>
> If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.
>       HRESULT error code:0x80020009
>         Exception occurred.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the relative position to your scriptfile itself, something like

```
path = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../Automated Testing/MasterFile.xls"
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(path)
```

I can't be sure where your script file resides so you need to adapt the number of /../ references.

Comment: Thanks Peter it worked  `path = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../../../MasterFile.xls"
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(path)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try,

```
path = "#{Dir.pwd}/Automated Testing/MasterFile.xls"
workbook = excel.WorkBooks.Open(path)
```

`Dir.pwd` will output your current project directory absolute path.

```
Dir.pwd
#> "/home/rails/projects/earthE/Blog"
```